# how to push dom html return into array in php?

Tags: php, html, arrays, xpath, scraper

This scrape returns:

- line 1:date
- line 2:home team
- line 3:score
- line 4:away team (same 4 elements repeated until the end)

I have tried everything to convert to an array, however no additions to this code have got the desired result, which would be something like a loop to give:

`[1]date [2]home [3]score [4]away` etc.

until the end of doc.

```
<?php 
$html = file_get_contents('http://www.soccerstats.com/round_details.asp?league=brazil'); //get the html returned from the following url

$doc = new DOMDocument();

libxml_use_internal_errors(TRUE);

if(!empty($html)){

  $doc->loadHTML($html);
  libxml_clear_errors(); //remove errors (html)

  $xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);

$rows = $xpath->query('//b/font');

  if($rows->length > 0){
      foreach($rows as $row){
         // $array[] = $row->nodeValue . "<br/>";
$array = $row->nodeValue . "<br/>";


print_r ($array);
      }
  }
}

?>
```

results:

```
1 Jun 14
Â FluminenseÂ 
1 - 1
Â InternacionalÂ 
1 Jun 14
Â VitÃ³riaÂ 
0 - 1
Â Sport RecifeÂ 
1 Jun 14
Â CorinthiansÂ 
1 - 1
Â BotafogoÂ 
1 Jun 14
Â ChapecoenseÂ 
2 - 1
Â BahiaÂ 
1 Jun 14
Â CruzeiroÂ 
3 - 0
Â FlamengoÂ 
1 Jun 14
Â SantosÂ 
2 - 0
Â CriciÃºmaÂ 
1 Jun 14
Â GrÃªmioÂ 
0 - 0
Â PalmeirasÂ 
1 Jun 14
Â FigueirenseÂ 
1 - 3
Â AtlÃ©tico PRÂ 
31 May 14
Â SÃ£o PauloÂ 
2 - 1
Â AtlÃ©tico MGÂ 
31 May 14
Â CoritibaÂ 
3 - 0
Â GoiÃ¡sÂ 
30 May 14
Â BahiaÂ 
0 - 2
Â SantosÂ 
29 May 14
Â InternacionalÂ 
2 - 0
Â ChapecoenseÂ 
29 May 14
Â FlamengoÂ 
1 - 1
Â FigueirenseÂ 
29 May 14
Â AtlÃ©tico MGÂ 
2 - 0
Â FluminenseÂ 
29 May 14
Â AtlÃ©tico PRÂ 
2 - 2
Â SÃ£o PauloÂ 
29 May 14
Â CorinthiansÂ 
1 - 0
Â CruzeiroÂ 
29 May 14
Â GoiÃ¡sÂ 
0 - 0
Â VitÃ³riaÂ
```

Comment: Can you format your question properly? The results can be formatted as code (select it and press Ctrl + K). It's not readable in its current state.

Comment: sorry, I have added the results

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, you are already on the right path, you need to separate first the values on the tables, then from there you can use `getElementsByTagName` to reach for your desired values.

Consider this example: [**Sample Fiddle**](http://codepad.viper-7.com/4KWc09)

```
$data = array();
$html = file_get_contents('http://www.soccerstats.com/round_details.asp?league=brazil'); //get the html returned from the following url
$doc = new DOMDocument();
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);

if(!empty($html)){
    $doc->loadHTML('<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">'.$html);
    libxml_clear_errors();
    $xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);

    $entries = $xpath->query('//table[@class="stat"]');
    foreach($entries as $key => $value) {

        $data[] = array(
            'date' => trim($value->getElementsByTagName('font')->item(0)->nodeValue),
            'home' => trim($value->getElementsByTagName('font')->item(1)->nodeValue),
            'score' => trim($value->getElementsByTagName('font')->item(2)->nodeValue),
            'away' => trim($value->getElementsByTagName('font')->item(3)->nodeValue),
        );
    }
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($data);
echo "</pre>";
```

[**Sample Fiddle**](http://codepad.viper-7.com/4KWc09)

Comment: Nailed it! thanks so much mate, exactly the result i was after